Find local minima of array including the first element of plateau
I refactored a code that finds the indices of local minima of the negative part of an array.
The original code identified as minima also the first element of a flat, but the new code doesn't and I couldn't find a way.
This is a MWE:
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

test = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, -1, -1, -2, -3, -2, 0])

wanted_mins = np.where(((test[:-2] > test[1:-1]) * (test[2:] >= test[1:-1])) & (test[1:-1] < 0))[0] + 1

refactored_mins = signal.find_peaks(np.negative(np.where(test<0, test, 0.0)))[0]

The wanted_mins are 6 and 9, but the refactored_mins is just 9.
How can I obtain also the first element of plateau points?

Why would you refactor this code? find_peaks has a much more complex logic than the numpy approach, which is why the results are different.

I was trying to find a more clear way to do it. Happy to find another numpy way

what's unclear about the original approach?

You could use np.nonzero((np.diff(test[:-1])<0) & (np.diff(test[1:])>=0) & (test[1:-1] < 0))[0] + 1 to have the same result if diff is more explicit to you
